# array values with where condition in laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I have an array called `assetIDs` as below

```
$assetIDs = Collection {#505 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => 4
    1 => 7
  ]
}
```

and I have the data in the table as below shown

[image: data]

and I'm doing query on the above table using this

`$supplier_id = SupplierAsset::whereIn('asset_id',$asset_ids)->pluck('supplier_id');`

and result for the above query is below

```
Collection {#510 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
  ]
}
```

here `whereIn` is returning all the possible rows which satisfies the condition. Actually I need to get the result as like which `supplier_id` has both the values of `assetIDs` array.In my table `supplier_id=1` has the both values `4` and `7` Just like below collection.

```
Collection {#510 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
  ]
}
```

Can anybody suggest me the solution for this please?

Comment: I have the answer in mysql but i don't know laravel, you are mixing 2 queries : - first you want to get which supplier_id **having** 2 different values                     - Second you want to display it

Comment: @Jean Doux: Okay can you help me with mysql query please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$supplier_id = SupplierAsset::whereIn('asset_id',$asset_ids)
               ->groupBy('supplier_id')
               ->havingRaw('count(distinct asset_id) = ' . count($assetIDs))
               ->pluck('supplier_id');
```

Comment: I've tried this already. It excludes the repeated values that's it .

Comment: Without goupBy it returns only one `supplier_id`. In your case it has no difference, but if you have large data it goes to error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mysql you should do :

1- get all the id who have more than 1 supplier_id :

```
SELECT supplier_id, Count(distinct asset_id) as dist_asst
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY supplier_id
 HAVING dist_asst > 1
```

2- then doing a join :

```
SELECT t1.supplier_id
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT supplier_id, Count(distinct asset_id) as dist_asst
     FROM Table
     GROUP BY supplier_id
     HAVING dist_asst > 1) t2 on t2.supplier_id = t1.supplier_id
```

Comment: let me check these two queries

Comment: Your queries are returning all the supplier IDs but this query works for me `SELECT supplier_id
FROM supplier_assets
WHERE asset_id IN ('4', '7')
GROUP BY supplier_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = `  But when i convert this into laravel its returning null :(

Comment: What is the result of the 1st query ?